# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 21641 (char 21640)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am getting the error as described in the title when calling the function:

```
def read_file(file_name):
    """Return all the followers of a user."""
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = []
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line.strip()))
    f.close()
    return data
```

Sample data looks like this:

```
"from": {"name": "Ronaldo Naz\u00e1rio", "id": "618977411494412"}, 
"message": "The king of football. Happy birthday, Pel\u00e9!", 
"type": "photo", "shares": {"count": 2585}, "created_time": "2018-10-23T11:43:49+0000", 
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/ronaldo/photos/a.661211307271022/2095750393817099/?type=3", 
"status_type": "added_photos", 
"reactions": {"data": [], "summary": {"total_count": 51779, "viewer_reaction": "NONE"}}, 
"comments": {"data": [{"created_time": "2018-10-23T11:51:57+0000", ... }]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse each line of the file as JSON on its own, which is probably wrong. You should read the entire file and convert to JSON at once, preferably using `with` so Python can handle the opening and closing of the file, even if an exception occures.

The entire thing can be condensed to 2 lines thanks to `json.load` accepting a file object and handling the reading of it on its own.

```
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

Comment: I tried this, now I get: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1240)`

Comment: @mrPy Then the file is not properly formatted as JSON. This can be verified on one of the many online JSON validators, such as https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: you're right. Thank you, and your answer would be right I guess if my JSON would be alright.